# How do I store null value from input field when the input field is not necessarily required in JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp, email, servlets

JSP

```
email = request.getParameter("vemail");
String sql = "insert into regdriver(email)values ('"+email+"')";    
st=con.createStatement();
rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
```

HTML Tag

```
<input type="email" name="vemail" id="mail" placeholder="">
```

If I did not enter any value in email field the `null` value is stored in database. Apart from `null` value, I want nothing to be stored in database.

Comment: So if the field does not exist, you do not want any row inserted into the database?

Comment: No I want to insert all the row in the database but if the field is null then I just want the email field not to be inserted. I just escaped insertion of other rows here.

Comment: You can't *not* insert a value into a column. You can insert `NULL`, which signals to the database that there is no data.

Comment: I got my answer in the next answer. Thank you I now know what you want to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure about the OP's point, if you just don't want to modify database when the email is null, just add if statement as below.

```
email = request.getParameter("vemail");
if(email != null){
    String sql = "insert into regdriver(email)values ('"+email+"')";    
    st=con.createStatement();
    rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
}
```

Comment: @DipeshPaudel Please accept the answer if you think it did solve your problem,thx